# What is the best practice for linking python scripts

Tags: python

When linking scripts are there performance considerations when using os.system verses import? Next, when the imported script has imports that must be shared with the calling script is it okay to put those imports in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. It is completely irrelevant whether a script shares imports with a calling script: you still need to have those imports in that script, whatever happens, and PEP8 guidance is to put them at the top of the file.

Comment: As for the first question: you *never ever* should use `os.system()` to call other Python scripts. Just make sure they expose their behavior as functions, and import those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no, not to a significant degree. Quite apart from the fact that PEP8 says use import and use it at the top of your file rather than at the start of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, there is no difference between using it at the head of your file versus under the `if __name__` conditional.